# Asymptotic run time complexity

Tags: algorithm

given an unsorted list of integer numbers of 
elements, and to find the sum of all the numbers in the list, he will use the
following algorithms.

```
function Sum(A, left, right)
if left > right:
return 0
else if left = right:
return A[left]
mid = floor((left+right)/2)
lsum = Sum(A, left, mid)
rsum = Sum(A, mid+1, right)
return lsum + rsum + A[mid]  

function myMethod(A, N)
B = new Array of length 1
B[0] = Sum(A, 0, N-1)
return B
```

(a) Analyse the asymptotic run-time complexity of the method myMethods.
Give the worst-case and the best-case running time in terms of Θ notation.
Justify your answer.

(b) Explain briefly, in words, why the best-case inputs and the worst-case
inputs are the same for the myMethods.

tried to do it but struggling with the question , would like to get some answers. thanks in advance.

Comment: try to think about how many times any single element is accessed (A[ x ] ).

Comment: If you count the additions that directly contribute to the result of `Sum(A, left, right)`, there are `right-left` of them. If you prove that statement by induction, you have proved (a) and (b).

Answer (score 0):

To define the complexity of an algorithm in terms of Θ, it is necessary to get the asymptotic upper and lower bounds.

The lower bound of the function in Omega(n) because to compute the sum, you need to access all the elements at least once.

The upper bound is O(n), as the function won't access more than n elements.

Therefore the complexity is Θ(n).

Here, the best case or worst case input does not matter, as taking summation of the elements of the list/array is independent of the order of the elements.